# Does the iOS Direct Deployment feature of Adobe Flash CS6 take such a long time for everyone?

Tags: ios, ipad, flash, air

I've tried the iOS deployment feature of Flash professional CS6 for the first time but it takes about 2minutes to finish the deployment process using a plain new blank "Air for iOS" project. Does it usually take this long for everyone?

If it takes 2-3 mins to deploy a blank project, won't it take forever to deploy a complex app or game to my iPad2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new in Flash CS6 and iOS publishing but I can tell from my tests that a empty project or a big project take almost the same time to be published. 
Don't know exactly why.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's normal that it takes a while to deploy an air project.